# Yii 2: Can I access a variable in a view that's rendered by another view?

Tags: php, variables, scope, view, yii2

In Yii 2, following the MVC pattern the controller passes certain variables to the view. However, sometimes the view renders another view in itself.

For example in the default generated CRUD views, both create.php and update.php render the _form view:

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
]) ?>
```

Is it possible for me to use a variable passed by the controller to create.php in _form?

Say the controller renders it like this:

```
return $this->render( 'create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'myVar' => $myValue,
] );
```

Now I can access $myVar in create.php but I can't in _form (which is rendered by create.php. Is there anyway I can access this? Or do I need to explicitly pass it to form like this (in create.php):

```
return $this->render( '_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'myVar' => $myValue,
] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `render`-function uses `extract()` to convert your parameters into regular variables in the local function context, which is where the `include` of the file is done. That is how you "receive" those values in your view.

This means that if you call `render` (or any of the other variants) again within that view, it will create a new local context and the local variables from "above" won't be there. Which is why it is required that you pass along the variables to every call, as you already figured out yourself.

Comment: This is useful addition and explanation.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since this one comes with an explanation. I thought I needed to pass it with every call, but this one also explains why. Thank you!

Comment: Too bad there isn't an option to just pass the variables through with an easy way like this `$this->render('_partial', $this->variables)` or something like that. Where `$this` refers to a `\yii\web\View`. You would think the view knows his own passed-through variables, right?

Comment: If you don't mind dragging along things like the `_SERVER`, `_GLOBALS` and so on, you can always just use `get_defined_vars()`. It includes everything in the local scope as well. I would use it very sparingly though, can have an impact on the memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to continuously pass it to view where you want to access it.

**Example:**

In controller:

```
return $this->render('view1', ['var' => $value]);
```

In `view1`:

```
<?= $this->render('view2', ['var' => $var]) ?>
```

Then you can access variable `var` as `$var` in view `view2`.

Answer (score -1):

I used this to pass a variable from one view to another:

View1:

```
<?= $this->render('@app/views/layouts/_view2.php', ['hideCarousel' => TRUE]) ?>
```

View2:

```
<?php if (!isset($hideCarousel)): ?>
    ...
<?php endif; ?>
```